# Google Map Not working with HTTP

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to google map and simply loading google map for current location but `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` throw error(

> i.e. getCurrentPosition() no longer working on insecure connection

).

My Code looks like :

```
function initialize() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
            var sMap = null;
            var marker = null;
            sMap = new GMaps({
                div: '#regestration-map',
                zoom: 13,
                lat: p.coords.latitude,
                lng: p.coords.longitude ,
                //center: center,
                scrollwheel: false ,
                styles: [ {stylers: [ { "saturation":-100 }, { "lightness": 0 }, { "gamma": 1 } ]}]
             }); 
           marker = sMap.addMarker({
                lat: p.coords.latitude,
                lng: p.coords.longitude ,
                map :sMap,      
                icon : map_marker,
                title: "<div style = 'height:60px;width:200px'><b>Your location:</b><br />Latitude: " + p.coords.latitude + "<br />Longitude: " + p.coords.longitude
            }); 

            sMap.addListener('click',function(e){
                marker.setPosition(e.latLng);
                marker.title = "<div style = 'height:60px;width:200px'><b>Your location:</b><br />Latitude: " + e.latLng.lat() + "<br />Longitude: " + e.latLng.lng()
            });

            marker.addListener('click',function(e){
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                infoWindow.setContent(marker.title);
                infoWindow.open(sMap, marker);
            });
        });
    }else {
        alert('Geo Location feature is not supported in this browser.');
    }
}
```

I upload code in UAT env and connection was not secure means for demo purposes there was not any SSL layer.

is there any workaround solutions to get current Latitude and Longitude with HTTP connection?

Comment: I believe now it can work in `localhost` as its treated as secure.

Answer (score 2):

from google docs
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

> HTTPS or HTTP
>
> We think security on the web is pretty important, and
>   recommend using HTTPS whenever possible. As part of our efforts to
>   make the web more secure, we've made all of the Maps JavaScript API
>   available over HTTPS. Using HTTPS encryption makes your site more
>   secure, and more resistant to snooping or tampering.
>
> We recommend loading the Maps JavaScript API over HTTPS using the
>    tag provided above.
>
> If required, you can load the Maps JavaScript API over HTTP by
>   requesting http://maps.googleapis.com/, or http://maps.google.cn for
>   users in China.

Comment: I am just looking for workaround solution that somehow gives me current latLng